# Linq to Entities Where clause compare value that can be int or string

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, where-clause

I have a drop down list that will provide either a numeric or the word ANY.  I need to create a LINQ SELECT containing a WHERE clause that can mimic the following SQL:

```
var p varchar2(3);

select ... from ...   
where ( 
 ( (:p = 'ANY') and id  in (select distinct id from Ids) )
 or
 (:p='1' and id = 42)
)
```

ps: I will be using an expression tree to handle the OR aspect :-)

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like this?

```
string input = /***/
var result = Context.Entities
                    .Where(ent => (input == "ANY" 
                                      && Context.UserIds.Select(usr => isr.Id)
                                                        .Distinct()
                                                        .Contains(ent.Id))
                                   || (input == "1" && ent.Id == 42))
                    .Select(ent => /***/);
```

Disclaimer: written from memory, can contain compile-time errors (typo mistakes etc)